# VBA - Excel - How to write a formula in a cell instead of values using list objects

Tags: excel, vba, formula, listobject

I'm struggling with VBA and couldn't find a solution on internet.

This is what I'm trying to do.
I have an excel file with two sheets
First sheet is an extract from a Database (with many columns, an particulary one called "country"). It is formated as a ListObject
Second sheet is a Calculator that is counting the number of occurence of every country in the other sheet. It is also formated as a list object

For Example at the end I'll get:
France: 10
USA: 25
Italia: 30

I found how to calculate this using the Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf function.

Now my question is: Is it possible to write the formula in the cell, instead of writing the result ?
The objectif is to generate a sheet filled with formulas, so that when I change things in the Database sheet, then it will automatically recalculate my results.

This is my current code: It works, but I'd like to write a formula in the cell, instead of the result.
It there an easyway to do this ?

Thanks a lof for your help !
Regards,
J.

```
Dim i As Long

Dim CountryName As Variant
    
Dim KPI_LO As ListObject
Dim REVIEWEDDATA_LO As ListObject

'This is the list object with the database information
Set REVIEWEDDATA_LO = Worksheets(REVIEWEDDATA_SHEET_NAME).ListObjects(REVIEWEDDATA_LISTOBJECT_NAME)
'This is the list object where I'll store my results
Set KPI_LO = Worksheets(WASPKPI_SHEET_NAME).ListObjects(WASPKPI_LISTOBJECT_NAME)
 
'loop through each country column in the result sheet
For i = LBound(GetCountriesList) To UBound(GetCountriesList)
        'Get the name of the first country to find
        CountryName = GetCountriesList(i)
        
        'Count the number of occurence of this country in the column called COL_COUNTRY in the revieweddata List Object (in my database sheet).
        'This is what I'm trying to replace. I want to write a formula that do this calculation in the cell, instead of the result.
        KPI_LO.ListColumns(CountryName).DataBodyRange.Rows(1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(REVIEWEDDATA_LO.ListColumns(COL_COUNTRY).DataBodyRange, CountryName)
Next i
```

Comment: Could you post the complete code, from `Sub` to `End Sub`  including any accompanying function(s) .

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see the formula in a cell, then you can create a function and then just call that and pass through your values.

For example, create a module:

```
Function fn_Multiply(x As Double, y As Double) As Double

Dim z As Double
z = x * y

fn_Multiply = z

End Function
```

And use it in excel as a formula like this:

```
=fn_Multiply(A2,B2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDXLP.png)

Comment: Hello ! THanks a lot for this. I didn't know this was possible.

Comment: Does it mean that when I update a value in the other tab, then it will automatically update the result ?
I was initially looking for something that would translate my formula using the list object, into a formula with cells references. But this probably not possible (I mean not possible easily)

Comment: So the function will work from any cell that references it (provided it's in a module). And as soon as your spreadsheet is 'refreshed' it will calculate. Exactly like how you would use any other formulae, eg 'SUM', 'IF'. As far as I understood your query, you effectively want a formula that you can use/reference within the cell to perform the VBA calculations, rather than VBA outputting the result?

Comment: Actually I was more thinking of a translation of the vba formula, into an excel formula refering to the sheets and cells. But your proposition is probably much clear and more intelligent than what I was thinking about :-) Thanks ! I'll check this

Comment: sure np, let me know how it goes. if you need more examples you can just search 'Excel VBA functions'. Or if this helps as is, then you can mark as resolved.